# How to set title of TOC in Latex hyperref package

Tags: latex, hyperref

The latex hyperref package makes a really nice, linked table of contents, named according to section name.  However, the top level category is by default, the file name.  It seems I should be able to change this to the actual title, but I'm not finding any information on how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this is not a 'feature' of your PDF reader? It might try to use the PDFs title (unset by default), which you can set like this:

```
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle = {The title},
    pdfauthor = {You}
}
```

You might also want to check out the [TeX StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Indeed, it was the reader (Preview, Mac) causing the problem.  Also good point on the TeX SE.